# Jquery Search FAQ - Slight modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I asked a question before but I need a bit more information. I found this great snippet for searching FAQ items:

http://jsfiddle.net/pT6dB/

I want to find a question containing "round and "Earth". However, if I type "round Earth" in looks specifically for "round Earth" which it cant find. I want it to be an "AND" query.

Would this be an easy modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to search for each term individually, and build up a query.

```
var term = $(this).val().trim();

var words = term.split(' ');

var selector = "#result LI";

for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    selector += ':contains(' + words[i] + ')'
}

$(selector).show();
```

**Update:** Here's a fiddle for you, with added case-insensitivity

http://jsfiddle.net/pT6dB/

Comment: So, if I used your code and searched "Test Search" it would only should results which contained the word "Test" and "Search"? I can see that you are using trim and split functions and targetting the result LI but I am unsure about how I integrate it. Do I put this code below the .ready(function( {

Comment: @James Willson: you have to check for space in the search box; if there is space most likely a person is searching for 2 terms; so display results only if you find both.

Comment: Got ya. So we split every time we see the space (ie line2). The code makes sense to me on a basic level, but im new to jquery, I cant understand how you would integrate it. Can someone show me or should I have a whack at it?

Comment: I dont know jquery and im new to coding, but I had a go: http://jsfiddle.net/pT6dB/45/

Answer (score 0):

Updated Fiddle to search case Insensitive.

http://jsfiddle.net/pT6dB/161/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('LI STRONG').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // disable text selection
        $(this).parent().find('EM').slideToggle();
        return false; // disable text selection
        
        

    });


jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};


jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

    $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
        var s = $(this).val().trim();
        
        if (s === '') {
            $('#result LI').show();
            return true;
        }
        $('#result LI:not(:contains(' + s + '))').hide();
     
        $('#result LI:contains(' + s + ')').show();
        return true;
    });

}); // end document ready
```

```css
#faq EM {
display:none;
}

#faq LI STRONG {
font-weight:normal;
color:#246;
text-decoration:underline;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faq">
    <p><label>Search</label><br />
<input id="search" value="" size="30" /></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ul id="result">
  <li><strong>How round is the Earth?</strong><br /><br /><em>
  Very round.
  <br /><br /></em></li>
  <li><strong>How rectangular is paper?</strong><br /><br /><em>
  Very rectangular.
  <br /><br /></em></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- #faq -->
```