# Jquery Search FAQ - no case sensitive

Tags: jquery

Im using this Jquery Search FAQ : [Jquery Search FAQ - Slight modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704079/jquery-search-faq-slight-modification)

But i need it to find the matching word without case sensitive, how can I do this?

Edit: this is the code im using:

```js
$('#search').keyup(function(e) {
  var s = $(this).val().trim();
  if (s === '') {
    $('#result LI').show();
    return true;
  }
  $('#result LI:not(:contains(' + s + '))').hide();
  $('#result LI:contains(' + s + ')').show();
  return true;
});
```

```html
<ul id="result" class="faq-ul"><br>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""><i></i>
    <h2>Pregunta 1</h2>
    <p><br> Respuesta 1<br>
    </p>
  </li><br>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""><i></i>
    <h2>Pregunta 2</h2>
    <p><br> Respuesta 2<br>
    </p>
  </li>
  <p></p>
</ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery :contains() selector uppercase and lower case issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746882/jquery-contains-selector-uppercase-and-lower-case-issue)

Comment: Show your code, and what you have tried, we can help from there.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it may be a duplicate, I dont know how to apply the code you just referenced in my code

Comment: @MattBunch done, just added it

Comment: Copy the code from that answer, then use `icontains` instead of `contains` in your code

Comment: @CertainPerformance, works like a charm although I do not know what is happening, should i delete the post for beeing duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate, will delete once not accepted.

Comment: Exact duplicates like this one should be flagged and closed, rather than copying over from the canonical (plus, your code doesn't even work).

Comment: @CertainPerformance I dont know how did you do to find the other post, it doesnt even contains words like " no case sensitive" or insensitive

Comment: @Gaspar I googled the phrase [jquery contains case insensitive](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+contains+case+insensitive) and clicked on the top SO link.

Comment: @casper if you will un-accept this answer, I can delete it.

Comment: @MattBunc I dont know, im really confused by now, you guys suggest me what to do please

Comment: @casper just click the green check mark. I can do the rest.